# Build error: multiple definition of

Tags: c, build, header-files, multiple-definition-error

I have a header file, wich contain a **unsigned char array** that is in fact a ttf font file.
In a .c file i'm able to load the font, and to use it ( i include the ttf header file in the .c file),  but the problem is that when i'm trying to use this in another c file, i get one of those 2 errors;

First error that i can get say that my array is undeclared.

So i include the header file that contain my array, and i get the second error; Multiple definition of ...

Can someone help ? I dont understand.
I hope i'm clear in my explaination, and sorry for my approximative english :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `extern`.

In your header file, make:

```
extern unsigned char my_array[];
```

In *exactly one* `.c` file, defined the array.

Comment: `extern unsigned char my_array[];` maybe?

Comment: It worked :D Thanks a lot ! I'm gonna flag your answer in 5minutes !

Comment: @microbe - yep. If you defined the array in your header file, you'll get as many definitions of this array, as `.c` files include that header. And you need only one definition. So, using `extern` in the header file will solve your issue - all `.c` files, that include it, will see the array and it will be defined only once.